# Generate all polynomial terms of certain degree

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy, python-itertools

Having list of n terms

```
ts = ['t1','t2','t3',...,'tn']
```

there is a task to achieve all possible q-length combinations of this terms.

Thus, for

```
ts = ['t1','t2']
q = 4
```

the answer will be

```
[['t1','t1','t1','t1'],['t1','t2','t2','t2'],['t1','t1','t2','t2'],
 ['t1','t1','t1','t2'],['t2','t2','t2','t2']]
```

Here is my solution

```
powers = np.array(list(itertools.product(*[range(q+1)]*len(ts))))
powers = powers[np.where(np.asarray(map(sum, powers))==q)]
res = map(lambda ps_: flatten([ p*[t] for p,t in zip(ps_,ts) ]), powers)
```

where [flatten](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python/952952#952952) is function that produces list from list of lists.

While having the solution that produces the desired result, I wonder if there are simpler ways to tackle the problem?

Comment: Those are not permutations. They are probably combinations with replacement.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that, made a correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need are combinations with replacement. The simplest solution is to use the aptly named [`itertools.combinations_with_replacement`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement):

```
>>> list(itertools.combinations_with_replacement(ts,q))
[('t1', 't1', 't1', 't1'),
 ('t1', 't1', 't1', 't2'),
 ('t1', 't1', 't2', 't2'),
 ('t1', 't2', 't2', 't2'),
 ('t2', 't2', 't2', 't2')]
```

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was looking for!

Comment: @tarashypka no worries, it's hard to pin down the proper name until you learn what it is:)